# Flask Marshmallow JSON fields

Tags: python, marshmallow

I have defined a POST call would that needs data:

```
{
    "one" : "hello",
    "two" : "world",
    "three" : { 
                "ab": "123", 
                "cd": false 
              }
}
```

For this, I am able to define `one` and `two`, but unsure what is the right was to define `three`. How can I specify a JSON field in Marshmallow? I am able to define basic fields such as:

```
from marshmallow import Schema, post_load, fields

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, one, two=None):
        self.one = one
        self.two = two

class MySchema(Schema):
    one = fields.String(required=True)
    two = fields.String()

    @post_load
    def create_foo(self, data, **kwargs):
        return Foo(**data)
```

How do I define `three` in `MySchema`? Should I:

1. simply put it as a string and do manipulation to load it as a json using `json.loads()/json.dumps()`? Or is there a way to define it properly?
2. define it as a `fields.Dict`?
3. can I define a separate `Schema` for this field
4. should I extend `field.Field`?

I am looking at https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/api_reference.html, though still not sure. A JSON sub-field or a nested JSON seems like a common use-case, yet I am not able to find anything relevant on this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be done with nested schemas: https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/nesting.html

Your schema would look something like:

```
class MySchema(Schema):
    one = fields.String(required=True)
    two = fields.String()
    three = fields.Nested(ThreeSchema)

class ThreeSchema(Schema):
    ab = fields.String()
    cd = fields.Boolean()
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create your own field

```py
import json
from marshmallow import fields

class JSON(fields.Field):
    def _deserialize(self, value, attr, data, **kwargs):
        if value:
            try:
                return json.loads(value)
            except ValueError:
                return None

        return None
```

```py
...
from marshmallow import fields, Schema
from schemas.base import JSON

class ObjectSchema(Schema):
    id = fields.Integer()
    data = JSON()
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to support *arbitrary* nested values in the field, rather than defining a schema for them, you can use:

- `fields.Dict()` (to accept an arbitrary Python `dict`, or, equivalently, an arbitrary JSON object), or
- `fields.Raw()` (for arbitrary Python objects, or, equivalently, arbitrary JSON values)

An example script you can run that uses both of the above, based on the example in the question:

```
import json
from marshmallow import Schema, fields, post_load


class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, one, two=None, three=None, four=None):
        self.one = one
        self.two = two
        self.three = three
        self.four = four


class MySchema(Schema):
    one = fields.String(required=True)
    two = fields.String()
    three = fields.Dict()
    four = fields.Raw()

    @post_load
    def create_foo(self, data, **kwargs):
        return Foo(**data)


post_data = json.loads(
    """{
    "one" : "hello",
    "two" : "world",
    "three" : {
                "ab": "123",
                "cd": false
              },
    "four" : 567
}"""
)

foo = MySchema().load(post_data)
print(foo.one)
print(foo.two)
print(foo.three)
print(foo.four)
```

Comment: Maybe I missed something, but what about defining the column as a first-class JSON type, or add the sqlalchemy-json package and use type NestedMutableJson ?

Comment: @chrisinmtown who said there were any columns or SQLAlchemy involved? :) I guess that you are using marshmallow-sqlalchemy, but the question here is purely about Marshmallow - there's not a database column or SQLAlchemy model anywhere in sight!